# Angularjs Ionic JSON object not returning data

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, ionic-framework

I am trying to get data back from a web service, I have to approaches the first is calling the data from the controller which works here is the code

```
$http({
method: 'POST',
url: 'https://url_json.php',
headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset-UTF-8'},
transformRequest: function(obj) {
    var str = [];
    for(var p in obj)
    str.push(encodeURIComponent(p) + "=" + encodeURIComponent(obj[p]));
    return str.join("&");
},
  data: paramsVal
}).then(function(response){

$scope.myData = response.data.PlaceDetailsResponse.results[0].first_name;

console.log('my data',$scope.myData);
});

}
```

but I would like to share the data between controllers so I read service is the best options, so in my services.js I have:

```
.factory('userService', function($http){
return {
    getUsers: function(){
        return $http.post("https://url_json.php",
            {entry : 'carlo' ,
            type:'first_name',
            mySecretCode : 'e8a53543fab6f00ebec85c535e' 
        }).then(function(response){

            users = response;
            return users;
        });
    }
}

})
```

but when I call it from the controller with `var user = userService.getUsers();` returns the below in the console:

```
user is [object Object]
```

and inspecting element within chrome I only see:

```
user is Promise {$$state: Object}
```

Also in chrome when I drill down on Promise the data value = "".

Can anyone take a look at my services and see if I'm doing anything wrong.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.then` returns a promise. You're falling for the [explicit promise construction antipattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23803743/what-is-the-explicit-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-do-i-avoid-it).

```
getUsers: function(){
    return $http.post("https://url_json.php",
        {entry : 'carlo' ,
        type:'first_name',
        mySecretCode : 'e8a53543fab6f00ebec85c535e' 
    })
}
```

The above is all you need. Then, in your controller:

```
userService.getUsers()
.then(function(response) {
  $scope.data = response.data; // or whatever
});
```

I would recommend looking at [John Papa AngularJS style guide](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide). He has a lot of information about fetching service data, using it in controllers, etc.

Answer (score 0):

In your controller you will have to assign the user variable by resolving the promise return from the getUsers like below:

```
$scope.user = [];
$scope.error ="";

userService.getUsers().then(function(data){
  $scope.user = data
},function(err){
   $scope.error = err; 
});
```

Hope this helps.